# How can use another datepicker plugin in jquery querybuilder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jalali-calendar, jquery-query-builder

query builder uses bootstrap date picker and I want use Shamsi date picker (jalali-moment.js) in query builder JQuery plugin but i don't know how to do it , i want replace jalali-moment.js with bootstrap date picker , can anyone help me??
it is my code :

```
var rules_basic = {
              condition: 'AND',
              rules: [
              {
                id: 'date',
                operator: 'equal',
                value: '1991/11/17'
              },
               {
                condition: 'OR',
                rules: [{
                  id: 'category',
                  operator: 'equal',
                  value: 2
                }, {
                  id: 'category',
                  operator: 'equal',
                  value: 1
                }]
              }]
            };

$('#builder').queryBuilder({
              plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],

              filters: [
                  {
                    id: 'date',
                    label: 'Datepicker',
                    type: 'date',
                    validation: {
                      format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
                    },
                    plugin: 'datepicker',
                    plugin_config: {
                      format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
                      todayBtn: 'linked',
                      todayHighlight: true,
                      autoclose: true
                    }
                  } ,
              {
                id: 'category',
                label: 'Category',
                type: 'integer',
                input: 'select',
                values: {
                  1: 'Category 1',
                  2: 'Category 2'
                },
                operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
              }],
              rules: rules_basic
            });
```